# Questions about the "share" popover in Photos app (and other apps)

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

So, if you share a photo in the Photos app, it pops open this widget:

[image]

This looks like a standard `UIPopoverController` with some `UIButtons`. My question is: Is this a system resource as one unit? I have searched using words I thought might fit if it is, but have come up with nothing.

Okay, suppose it does not exist as a system resource. Is there a resource where I can get various sizes of these icons? Specifically the three in the top row. My app already provides functionality for each of these functions which I have coded up. These actions are just tied to ugly text only buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets asked a lot. It's a `UIActivityViewController`. It was added in IOS 6.0.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to search for 'activity'. 

Any idea where to get the icons as standalone image files? Since I have already implemented the actions, it would be easiest to just skin the buttons.

Comment: I recommend you use the activity controller as-is. It will save you a bunch of work and code.